# JavaScript unique path for C://Windows location on XP/W7/W8

Tags: javascript, windows

When several offline (local) html files using the same JavaScript file (script.js), what will be the unique path of that file if I put it in C://Windows/Script folder.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Windows/Script/submit.js"></script>
```

When I paste these html files on several other machines (using XP/W7/W8) and then create a folder Script in C://Windows and put there my **submit.js** file, will it has some problems? I mean, I assume that every computer has C://Windows folder on that location, so if I put this path in my JS file it will work if there is a js file there (I will put it manually there on every computer).

My question: is this C://Windows location different in Windows Xp or 7, or maybe it is different on every local machine?

*If somebody maybe installed Windows on other partition, then I will do it manually by changing the script path.*

Comment: No. On different PCs Windows can be installed on different drive _(see %SystemDrive%)_ and system folder can potentially have different name _(%SystemRoot%)_

Comment: Yes. I understand. And, if I create a folder directly on C://, not in the Windows folder... And change a script to be src="file:///C:/Script/submit.js"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't rely on c:\windows being the same for every machine. For windows paths in general, it's recommended to use an API to find them on any given system.

It would help a lot if you could provide an context for this script.  What is it being used in?

Comment: What about if I put in C://Script - and the Script will be the folder which I create on C, consisting my js file

Comment: If you can ensure that this doesn't exist on the client system for some other purpose, and you can ensure that it will be created, then sure.  This is why I asked about context.  Depending on how you were deploying, what you could assume and how you get do it would vary dramatically.